# Al abrir la página donde se encuentra el formulario php me muestra datos literales del código

Tags: php, sql, echo

[image: Muestra datos del código]
"; echo ""; echo "Id_traduccionPalabraSignoRegla"; echo ""; while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $Id_traduccion=$mostrar['Id_traduccion']; $Palabra=$mostrar['Palabra']; $Signo=$mostrar['Signo']; $Regla=$mostrar['Regla']; echo ""; echo "" .$Id_traduccion.""; echo "" .$Palabra.""; echo "" .$Signo.""; echo "" .$Regla.""; echo ""; echo ""; } echo ""; ?>

Comment: Sí, es mediante php y mysql

Comment: Todos tienen la extensión .php y las etiquetas también estan (<?php y ?>)

Comment: Es muy posible el servidor web no esté cargando el módulo de PHP instalado, y por tanto no se "interpreta" el código php.

Comment: Muestra el código completo, si esta mezclando HTML y PHP alguna etiqueta de bloque **<?php ?>** no esta cerrada correctamente o estas definiendo mal los bloques.